# Excel Pivot Chart

Tags: excel

I have a table that includes (among other things) month, state, and dollars. I can pivot the table so months are in rows, states are in columns, and dollars are in values. I am comparing (among other things) several different dollar categories, say $A, $B, and $C. When I attempt to chart them, however, I get totals for each state. Thus GA has A,B,and C, TN has A,B,and C, etc. 
My end goal is to slice the states, so I want total A, total B, and total C for whichever states are selected. Help?

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (howto: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get us better idea what you already have, how it works and what you want to achieve. Remove all the irrelevant information from your Excel and produce a clear example.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did this by changing the order of values/states across the columns so that my states where below the $ types, then grouping the states, and importantly COLLAPSING the groups. Seems to be working, I'll follow up if I have any problems.